# Finding the first 100 prime numbers

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find the FIRST 100 PRIME NUMBERS. Not the primes from 1-100. I need some help with this code.

```
    var p = function(n){
    var x = Math.sqrt(n);
    if(n==2){return 2;}
    else if (n % 2===0){return 0;}
    var i=3;
    for(i=3; i < x; i+=2){
            if(n%i===0){return 0;}
    }
    return n;
};


var firstKPrime = function(k){
        var i=1;
        var arr =[];
        for(i = 1; i < k+1; i++){
                if(i==2){arr.push(p(i));}
                if(i>2 && i%2!==0){
                        if (p(i)>1){arr.push(p(i));}}
                    }
                return arr;
            };

                var fmt = function(arr){
                    return arr.join(",");

            };

            var k = 100;
            console.log("firstKPrime(" + k + ")");
            console.log(fmt(firstKPrime(k)));
```

I dont want it to find the primes from 1-100 help me with modifying this

Comment: run a loop.  increment `i`, if it's a prime number, add it to an array, check to see the `.length` of the array.  When `.length = 100` stop the loop.

Comment: Precisely what help do you need?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Doing your homework at the last minute? ;-p

Comment: ha ha ha these questions are coming from Startup-Engineering Course...  Everyone seems to be running to complete the homework :D

Answer (score 8):

```
var first100primes = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,127,131,137,139,149,151,157,163,167,173,179,181,191,193,197,199,211,223,227,229,233,239,241,251,257,263,269,271,277,281,283,293,307,311,313,317,331,337,347,349,353,359,367,373,379,383,389,397,401,409,419,421,431,433,439,443,449,457,461,463,467,479,487,491,499,503,509,521,523,541];
```

Hehe...

In seriousness, though, you should follow the following pattern:

- Create an array `primes` and an integer `i=1`
- While `primes.length < 100`, do the following:

  - Increment `i`
  - For all integers `j` between `2` and `sqrt(i)`:

    - If `i % j == 0` then continue the top loop
  - If you reach this point, then it's a prime number, so push `i` onto `primes`

Example implementation of the above:

```
(function() {
    var primes = [2];
    window.getNprimes = function(n) {
        var i = primes.length == 1 ? 1 : primes[primes.length-1], j, l;
        main:
        while((l=primes.length) < n) {
            i += 2;
            for( j=0; j<l; j++) {
                if( i % primes[j] == 0) continue main;
            }
            primes.push(i);
        }
        return primes.slice(0,n);
    };
})();
```

This is as optimal as I can think of, in particular if you call `getNprimes(100)` several times, it will only calculate it the first time and just return the same result next time.

Comment: Seed primes with '2' and increment i by 2.

Comment: You don't need to test with `j` between 2 and `sqrt(i)`. Just test with all the previously found primes (this is the Sieve of Eratosthenes).

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, bit of a no-brainer when I think about it! Edited code.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a library like [Lazy.js](http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/) then you could simply do this:

```
var first100primes = Lazy
    .generate(infiniteSequence(2))
    .filter(isPrime)
    .take(100)
    .toArray();

function infiniteSequence(start, step) {
    if (typeof start === "undefined") start = 0;
    if (typeof step === "undefined") step = 1;

    return function (i) {
        return start + i * step;
    };
}

function isPrime(n) {
    var sqrtn = Math.sqrt(n);

    for (var i = 2; i <= sqrtn; i++)
        if (n % i === 0) return false;
    return true;
}
```

That's all. If you don't want to use Lazy.js then you could do this instead:

```
var first100primes = [], n = 2;
do if (isPrime(n++)) first100primes.push(n - 1);
while (first100primes.length < 100);

function isPrime(n) {
    var sqrtn = Math.sqrt(n);

    for (var i = 2; i <= sqrtn; i++)
        if (n % i === 0) return false;
    return true;
}
```

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a3mKv/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using for(i = 1; i < k+1; i++)
Use

```
j = 1;
i=2;
while(j <= k)
{
  if(i==2){arr.push(p(i));}
                if(i>2 && i%2!==0)
                {
                        if (p(i)>1)
                        {arr.push(p(i));j++;}
                }
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use the arr.length property to see how many primes have been found and compare that the parameter k.

Something along these lines:

```
var firstKPrime = function(k){
var i=1;
var arr =[];
while (arr.length < k)
{
    if(i == 2)
    { 
        arr.push(p(i)); 
    }

    if(i>2 && i%2!==0)
    {
        if (p(i)>1)
        {
            arr.push(p(i));
        }
    }

    i++;
}

return arr;
};
```

Comment: Why ever not? Note that the function p(i) is not defined in this piece of code and I inferred it's working from the **original code the author provided**. That piece of code finds the primes in a certain range, so the function p(i) must already work. Building on that, this code makes as little changes to original code as I could think of. Your downvote and comment makes me rather sad

Comment: So I just tested it again. I realized I forgot one i++; statement in the loop, but if that was all that was wrong with it, you could have just said so... Apart from that, code works absolutely fine. Really weird behaviour from your side.